# Code formatting loading fails

Tags: bug, android-app

If a

```
non-inline code formatting
```

(on Stack Overflow) is very long, the end of it will not be loaded, it's still white.

Like on this screenshot:

[image]

Here: ^^^

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-A520F
- OS Version: 8.0.0 (A520FXXU7CRJG)